# How to execute drawer layout in oncreate in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I am developing android application with drawer layout in fragments. actually i am trying to display drawer layout in oncreate in fragments but it is not coming 
i have oncreate and oncreateview override method in fragments and whenever application open that time only my drawer layout should come.
this is my oncreate

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      } 

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test2, container, false);

           mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        navDrawerItems.add("first");
        navDrawerItems.add("second");
        navDrawerItems.add("third");

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getActivity(),navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
      }
```

My Requirements:-
   My **loadingswipe()** function should execute whenever application open that is the reason i am giving **loadingswipe()** inside oncreate. if i give this function in oncreateview, it is executing while clicking back button also but my requirement is it should not execute while clicking back button. could you please help me to resolve this issues.

Update:-
   Now i have given my drawer layout in my oncreateview Now my drawer layout is showing but the problem is inside test2 i have one button if click that enter into that page but whenever i click back button that time  drawer layout also showing but for me that button only should show

Comment: you´re inflating a layout but it is never attached to a visible component at all. you see that?

Comment: @eduyayo yes you are right but how can i attach my layout to visible component?

Comment: yup yup. This: `final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test3, null);` that layout goes nowhere.

Comment: @eduyayo I have two layouts R.layout.test2 and R.layout.test3 actually test2  is my normal layout but i have to show test3 on top of test2. In test2 layout i have given drawer layout when ever app open my drawer layout should open we can swipe it back and as usual my test2 layout should be there

Comment: ok, I see. so you just wanna run this method once and only when creating... When restoring you can knwo when the fragment is restoring by checking if the `savedInstanceState != null`

Comment: @eduyayo see my update question i should not execute  these drawer layout  code while clicking back button

Comment: @eduyayo i am trying to check `savedInstanceStace !=null` but always i am getting null could you please help me